# Junit: testing service with private @Autowired fields

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, integration-testing

I have been doing Junit tests the past few weeks so my experience, being a junior programmer is fairly limited. After testing the easier service classes in the project, now I am stuck.
The problem is that I can't inject some `private final someRepository` into the constructor of the service class that I am testing, namely:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeRepository someRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void testMyFunc() {
        SomeOtherDto param = new SomeOtherDto();
        param.setVar1(...);
        param.setVar2(...);
        Mockito.when(someRepository.getIt()).thenReturn(-1L);
        Mockito.when(someService.myPrivBoolBuilder(param,-1L))                                                                                     
                                             .thenReturn(new BooleanBuilder());
        Pageable pageable = null;
        Page<SomeDto> result = someService.myFunc(param, pageable);
        assertEquals(expResult, 
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

and the service I am testing:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SomeService implements someAbstractService {
    private final CustomMapper customMapper
    private final SomeRepository someRepository;
    private final SomeOtherRepository someOtherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(final CustomMapper customMapper, final SomeRepository someRepository, 
                       final SomeOtherRepository someOtherRepository, etc) 
    { /* ... */ }

    public Page<SomeDto> myFunc(final SomeOtherDto param, final Pageable pageable) {
        final BooleanBuilder predicate = myPrivBoolBuilder(param, 
                                             someOtherRepository.getId());  
        return someRepository.findAll(predicare, pageable).map(obj -> {  
                                             return customMapper.map(obj) });
    }

    public BooleanBuilder myPrivBoolBuilder(final SomeOtherDto param, final Long id) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        final QSomeRepository qSomeRepository = QSomeRepository.someRepository;
        final QSomeOtherRepository qSomeOtherRepository  = QSomeOtherRepository.someOtherRepository();
        predicate.and(qSomeRepository.someField.someOtherField.goe(param.getX()));
        predicate.and(qSomeRepository.someField2.someOtherField2.isNotNull()));
        predicate.and(qSomeOtherRepository.someField.someOtherField.id.eq(id()  
            .or(qSomeOtherRepository.someField.someOtherField.id.in(...))));
        return predicate;        
    }   
    /* ... */    
}
```

My problem is that when I run the test `someOtherRepository.getId()` return `null` with `SpringRunner.class`. When I run with `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` the `someService` constructor throws a constructor error:  `someRepository is NULL`
I have tried multiple ways (tried `@Spy`, `@MockBean`, `Mockito().doReturn...` syntax, etc), but these are the two errors I get. I'm pretty sure it's a matter of using the Mocking framework correctly.
If you need other snippets or details, I will kindly offer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Mockito tries to construct the object because of the `@InjectMocks` annotation.

`SpringRunner` is not necessary as this is not a spring test. If you really want a special runner, you can go for `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

You can simply initialize the Mockito annotations in your `Before` method and then create your service instance with the constructor providing the mocked dependencies.

```
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    private SomeService someService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         someService = new SomeService(someRepository);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but now the problem is this line: `Mockito.when(someService.myPrivBoolBuilder(param,-1L))                                                                                     
                                             .thenReturn(new BooleanBuilder());`  
The runtime error is `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'`.

Comment: You are trying to mock a method call on a real object (someService). You have to mock the someRepository.

Comment: You are right.   
Is there any method (something like `@Spy`, but to also inject that pesky `SomeRepository`) with which I can mock that function call?

Comment: You can do it like `someService = Mockito.spy(new SomeService(someRepository))`. However, please think about what you really wanna test as I think using Spy with Mocks are most of the time is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [ReflectionTestUtil](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) provided by Spring to inject a mock of SomeRepository from the test class.

eg; 
`ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someService, "someRepository", mock(SomeRepository.class));`